# What is the right way to '#include file' in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to do something like this:

```
<!--#include file="../stuff/foo/box.aspx"-->
```

But doing this in an ASP.Net MVC application it just feels wrong.  Is there a better way of achieving the same thing in a ASP.Net MVC project ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<%: Html.Partial("~/Views/foo/box.ascx") %>
```

or:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/foo/box.ascx"); %>
```

or the best of them all use an [editor template](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/08/13/HtmlDisplayForInAspNetMvc2.aspx) (if this partial contains inputs for editing the view model property):

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyModelProperty) %>
```

or a display template (if this partial contains only display of view model property):

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyModelProperty) %>
```

and their Razor equivalence

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/foo/box.ascx")
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/foo/box.ascx");}
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyModelProperty)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyModelProperty)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make a partial view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Html.RenderPartial('~/Views/Login/Box.ascx');
```

RenderPartial allows to render part of the page using the same context. If you want to render using new context, use

```
Html.RenderAction("Box","Login"); //Box - Action, Login - Controller
```