# Render An aspx File (Menu Bar) in Razor View Layout Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been looking around looking for a solution for this issue but have yet to arrive to a solution that works. I was using this as a reference but couldn't get anything to work:[What is the right way to '#include file' in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021763/what-is-the-right-way-to-include-file-in-mvc)

I have an MVC 4 project that uses a Razor for the views and I want to add an aspx page that contains a menu bar that I would to add to the _LayoutPage.cshtml. As of right now I have recreated the menu so it looks the same in my razor view but the issue is that when a change needs to be made to the menu.aspx page I have to make the same changes in my razor view.

So my goal is to just render this menu in my layout.cshtml page.

This is what i have right now but it does not work. Is there anyway to do this?

```
<div id="page-header">
    @Html.RenderPartial("P:/menu/menu.aspx")
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply take menu.aspx and turn it into a view partial?

Answer (score 0):

Place your **.aspx** file in `Views` foulder and then:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/WebForms/menu/menu.aspx")
```

Also, could be that it is not working becouse `RenderPartial` works other way, try:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("P:/menu/menu.aspx"); }
```