# How to reference a global virtual include in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My company has a set of global virtual files that they want to use for the look and feel of the site.  In the ASP days you would use #include virtual="etc".  These are files outside of the application.

In ASP.NET you could use something like Response.WriteFile...

But if I try that in an MVC View then I get the content always at the top of the page, not where I want it in position.

How would I approach doing this in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021763/what-is-the-right-way-to-include-file-in-mvc

Comment: @DavidTansey: That's pretty old.  Is it still the canonical way to do it?

Comment: Ahhh, that could work as well.  I didn't think you could reference .ascx files within a PartialView if you're using Razor as your view engine.  See how I did it below.  Yes, it looks like a kluge but actually works.  I'll look at your solution as well.  Actually that solution you posted wouldn't work for me because the includes have to be located in a central location well outside of the directory structure of the application.  Since someone may change content in the include globally, if I had the content within the application, I wouldn't be picking up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this to work.  I HAD to work with these old virtual includes, I had no choice for the company.

I did this in the layout:  I basically had to inject the includes with a Response.WriteFile to the place up the directory tree where the includes were located.  These includes are used for ALL web sites in our company.  Then I used a StringBuilder to build the content within the layout.  I also had to put the @RenderBody statement within the Response object as well.

```
@using System.Text;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="Software that excels. Training that inspires.   Build your company mobile presence on Android and Apple."/>
   <meta name="title" content="Software that excels.  Training that inspires.  Build your company mobile presence on Android and Apple." />
   <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="keywords" content="software, training, Android, mobile, iOS, Apple, data, visualization" />    
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link rel="icon" href="~/Content/favicon3.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    @{
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    Response.WriteFile("../../includes/header.inc");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4000);
    sb.Append("<div class=\"container body-content\">");
    sb.Append(@RenderBody());
    sb.Append("<hr />");
    sb.Append("<footer>");
    sb.Append("<p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Excellor Software</p>");
    sb.Append("</footer>" + "</div>");
    sb.Append("</div>");

    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();
    sb = null;
    Response.WriteFile("../../includes/footer.inc");
    }
  </body>
  </html>
```